# data factory dataflow - convert exponential to decimal

Tags: azure-data-factory

in dataflow, I am using this expression to convert exponential numbers to decimal but if it is 1E-07 it does not seem to be able to convert.
And I would like to remove the leading 0's if possible
Any thoughts?

iif(like(volumn1, '%E%'), toString(toDecimal(column1, 20, 10)), column1)

Answer (score 1):

solved by using formats of the following #.######